# How to delete textures in OpenGL 2.x?

Tags: objective-c, memory, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1) to create a basic game using OpenGL and after profiling it, discovered that even after a sprite is removed, the textures are not being released creating a memory leak. I easily fixed the problem by creating a cache in the Sprite class, but I would like to know how I can delete the texture itself for future reference. It is loaded with `GLKTextureLoader`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GLuint index = self.textureInfo.name;
glDeleteTextures(1, &index);
```

Comment: I tried using `glDeleteTextures` before, but when I gave it the parameters `(1, &self.textureInfo.name)`, it gave me an error. This works, but why do you have to make the `GLuint index` variable first for it to work?

Comment: Because 'name' is property. When you retrieve the value, it may have been implemented as a function. glDeleteTexture(1, &getName()) is wrong.